# Manipulating microsoft word

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am currently writing this application to print and create a report to a new word document. However I have met a stumbling block. Is their any way while I am writing the data to this new Microsoft word doc to check if its a new page so for example the report takes up 10 pages, Is their a way to check when the application starts writing on a new page?

---

**Code:**

```
Dim objWord 
As Word.Application
Dim objDoc As Word.Document
Dim objTable As Word.Table
Dim r As Integer, c As Integer
Dim pages1 As Pages
Dim pagecountbefore As Integer

objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add

pagecountbefore = pages1.Count

objTable = objDoc.Tables.Add(objDoc.Bookmarks.Item("\endofdoc").Range, 3, 5)
objTable.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 6
For r = 1 To 1000
    For c = 1 To 5
         If r = 1 Then
            Select Case c
                Case "1"
                    objTable.Cell(r, c).Range.Text = "PCI DSS Requirements "
                Case "2"
                    objTable.Cell(r, c).Range.Text = "Testing Procedures "
                Case "3"
                    objTable.Cell(r, c).Range.Text = "In Place"
                Case "4"
                    objTable.Cell(r, c).Range.Text = "Not in Place"
                Case "5"
                    objTable.Cell(r, c).Range.Text = "Target Date/ Comments"
            End Select
        Else
            If pagecountbefore<pages1.Count Then
                pagecountbefore = pages1.Count
                Select Case c
                    Case "1"
                        objTable.Cell(r, c).Range.Text = "PCI DSS Requirements "
                    Case "2"
                        objTable.Cell(r, c).Range.Text = "Testing Procedures "
                    Case "3"
                        objTable.Cell(r, c).Range.Text = "In Place"
                    Case "4"
                        objTable.Cell(r, c).Range.Text = "Not in Place"
                    Case "5"
                        objTable.Cell(r, c).Range.Text = "Target Date/Comments"
                End Select
            Else
              'print resultrs from database
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: I'm curious. Why do you care about pages? Why not let Word handle pagination?

Comment: Because I am trying to simulate this report that my company has, through a windows application. Each new page has the table headers so i am trying to find out how I can do this

Comment: I mean Word can be set up to do headers and footers so you don't need to know.

Comment: Yea I know about headers and footers but as I said this is a table and this should be the titles for the tables

Answer (score 0):

You can check the page count of your word document every time and create an if-clause that does something then.

You can count the pages with:

```
myPageObject.Count //returns int
```

Then check for new pages every time you write data.

```
//Writing Data 
if(pagecountbefore < myObjectPage.Count){
    //Do Something 
}
```

Or you can do it with an while clause:

```
  while(pagecountbefore == myObjectPage.Count){
       //Do Something 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the kind reply. However this is the deal let me break it down some more. I will have a data reader running and while it is reading from the database i will create this new document and then create a table with the size of the amount of rows related to the query.  so if its 50 rows it will be a table with 5 columns ( for example firstname, lastname, job, country, address) and 50 rows. Now while this is reading i will want the application whenever it reaches a new page in the document to print the headers of the columns again

Comment: (firstname, lastname, job, country, address) then continue to insert the data until it finishes. is there a specific way to do that?

Comment: And i created an object by using this code Dim objDoc As Word.Document however when i try to reference it and get the count there is none available...

Comment: You have to use `Dim myPageObject As Pages`.
Take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.pages.count%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Please fill your question with some code, then maybe I could create something.
But the if-clause should work for that case.
`if(pagecountbefore < myObjectPage.Count){
    CreateNewTable();
    WriteDateLastTable();
}else{
    WriteDateLastTable();
}`

Comment: I got an object reference error at this line pagecountbefore = pages1.Count and i did declare this before Dim pages1 As Pages. So i dont know why?

Comment: what value should I give to pages1 after declaring it

Comment: this is for office 2012 and vb.net 2008 any help?

Comment: I still havent received a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Why don;t you just set the first row of the table to be a header row after inserting all the rows just say 
objTable.Rows(1).HeadingFormat = True

if will then show at the top of every page the table spans